# Galaxy S5 won't connect to laptop (tried everything I could find)

Tags: connection-issues, samsung-galaxy-s-5, usb-connection-mode

Alright so I'm sure this is something that people ask a lot, but mine seems to be some sort of super weird case of "heck you I don't wanna mate with your laptop."

My Galaxy just will not connect to my laptop no matter what I do. I'm starting to think maybe it's just an issue with my laptop but idk how it could be.

**The big things I've tried so far**

- Using Developer Mode to enable USB debugging.
- Dialing *#0808# in order to select MTP
- Connecting my phone to my laptop through Bluetooth

**Some important things to note**

- When I pull down my phone's notification bar, there is no selection for Connect or whatever.
- I have tried to restart my phone after making changes.
- My computer doesn't recognize my phone as a bluetooth or connect device (but can pick up my boyfriend's phone as bluetooth)

I really don't know what to do. I just want to move photos onto my computer but nothing I'm finding online is helping at all. Is there any setting in my computer that I can change in order to fix this? I've tried doing every small and big method I can find online for the past month or so.

Thank you.

Comment: What OS does your computer have? If Windows, did you install drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not detecting your phone via usb , you should try changing the cable, try that

Comment: This or an issue with the USB port is likely an issue.

Comment: I don't know if I want to spend the money on buying a brand new charger when this one is only a few months old and worked fine on my old laptop. I've also tested all USB ports with multiple things and they work fine.

Comment: Actually, I might have a spare

Comment: It worked, thank you so much omg. That's super weird that this new one will work with my old laptop but not this one. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Star-Lord as it solved your issue, please consider marking it the "accepted solution" (tick the check-mark next to the answer). Thanks!